# Create org from environment hub org with experience cloud licenses

Tags: experience-cloud, environment-hub

So in my PBO, I have environment hub enabled. Since our app that we are creating is for the experience cloud and dependent on it. I would like to create an org from environment hub for dev and testing. Although I can select the type of Org like Enterprise, Professional etc. How do I provision an Enterprise org from Environment hub with Experience cloud licenses assigned to it so that I can create site in it and test my package in it?

By default, whichever org you create from environment hub is created with the standard sales and service cloud licenses. I know creating one with different cloud licenses is possible but I'm just not sure how?

Answer (score 1):

I unfortunately don't have access to a PBO to look at what licenses are included in the Partner Enterprise Edition and Partner Developer Edition orgs.  I know each org comes with different sets of licenses so if you've tried the Partner EE org, you might try a Partner DE org.  Other than that, the only option I know of is to contact Partner Support.

However, if the goal is to create an org to test a package, why not use scratch orgs?  Getting a scratch org with Experience Cloud licenses is as easy as adding "Communities" to the scratch org definition file's features section and then configuring some settings.

Here are relevant sections from a scratchdef file...

```
{
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": "Communities",
  "settings": {
    "communitiesSettings": {
      "enableNetworksEnabled": true,
      "enableGuestRecordReassignOrgPref": true,
      "enableOotbProfExtUserOpsEnable": true
    }
  }
}
```

You can see a complete working file here:
https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Grants-Management-Installers/blob/main/orgs/release.json#L29-L33

Comment: Jason, thank you for your thoughts. You are absolutely right about the scratch org part. I have that but the problem is that I use a B2C store to test our app. Now we can build that store with all the products but it is a lengthy process that I would have to repeat every month with a scratch org as that is the maximum period before it expires. With environment hub, I get the option to atleast have it persist for 3-4 months. 

I'll open a case with partner support around this I guess.